# For some reason IE8 is not cool with inherited html5 CSS in my Sass files?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple line like so :

```
 #footer {
    position:relative;
    border-top:1px solid #cecece;
    z-index:20;
  }

  #footer ul.footer-row {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 32px;
  }
```

And IE9 IE10 all works fine and dandy. But for some reason IE8 does not render any of the lines in this css unless I take it out from #footer and place it by itself as so :

```
 #footer {
  position:relative;
  border-top:1px solid #cecece;
  z-index:20;
 }

 ul.footer-row {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 32px;
 }
```

So what weird rule is IE8 following here? Totally stumped.

**This is my SCSS :**

```
#footer {
  position:relative;
  border-top:1px solid #cecece;
  z-index:20;
  nav#footer_inside {
     font-size:14px;
     margin:0 auto;
     ul.footer-row {
       float: left;
       margin: 0 32px;
       a { margin-bottom: 2px; }
     }
  }
}
```

And this is what it compiles to and effectually ignored.

```
#footer nav#footer_inside ul.footer-row {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 32px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot the HTML5 shiv? It's hard to tell without a SSCCE.

Comment: HTML5 Shiv? You mean my DTD? I tried Standard and HTML5, no go if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: Is this your compiled CSS or your SCSS? There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, but there is no doubt an error elsewhere in your code that is causing what you see.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after z-index, no idea if that's the problem but you should probably add one :)

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ (you can make one at http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com), HTML5 shiv is a script that allows HTML5 elements (`section`, `footer`, `article`) to be styled in IE8.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - the OP isn't using any HTML5 elements here

Comment: @Adam Let me borrow your crystal ball for a moment - there's no HTML posted here.

Comment: Or you have a structural error in the HTML that causes IE8 to think the ul is not in the footer. IE8 does handle some errors differently than IE9.

Comment: @teabos That is not an error; it is perfectly valid and no browser ever had a problem with that.

Comment: @MrLister yep that sounds more like it. But really hard to tell without markup or fiddle.

Comment: Updated the semicolon error. Added my scss and its compilation.

Comment: Ah perhaps IE8 does not recognize `<footer>` tags? I didn't include that. And Fabricio's html5 nose may be magnificent.

Comment: @MrLister never said it was the problem, it's just good practice

Comment: @Trip it doesn't recognize `<nav>` either which your CSS is targeting.

Comment: WOW Fabricio Matté. You are genius status. I grant you the medallion of outshining shininess. I can't believe you guess that without even seeing code. Unbelievable.

Comment: @Trip heheh a lot of time in Stack Overflow yields some psychic powers.

Comment: Mhm so do you already have the shiv? Back to point zero then.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue on http://jsbin.com (or similar) and we will take another look. `=]`

Comment: FAbricio! you were right! The Shiv worked!!

Comment: Oh Ok then, I've undeleted the answer. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [HTML5 shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) to the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

IE<=8 by default does not style element whose tag names it doesn't recognized. This is changed when the given tag name is passed to `document.createElement()`, and that's basically what the shiv does with all HTML5's new tag names.

Historically, this "hack" has been discovered in the early stages of the HTML5 standardization process, thus propelling the adoption of HTML5 semantics.

Comment: Ah got it. My html5 shiv was outdated ( or something ).. Haha thanks so much Fabricio Matté. *flips hat*